# Is respect awarded, accorded or afforded?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, orthography, collocation, eggcorn

I was revising a colleague's work, and saw the phrase "awarded the respect it deserves". This struck me as incorrect, but I was struck harder still by an uncertainty as to whether it actually is, compounded by an inability to choose between "accorded" and "afforded" as a replacement.

Google searching implies that "awarded" is largely out of use, but "accorded" and "afforded" each appear at comparable frequency, changing depending on the context.

I can't help but feel that there's some eggcorning going on here. Does anybody have an inside track on whether either or both (or all three, why not?) are correct?

Comment: In my world respect has to be _earned_.

Comment: Very interested. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=afforded+the+respect%2Cawarded+the+respect%2Caccorded+the+respect&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) suggests _accorded_ is the most prevalent but that doesn't necessarily mean in the usage you're thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a collocate search in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) to get some solid numbers.

The verbs with the intended meaning that collocate most with "respect" (collocate search for `respect` and `VERB`, group by lemmas) are **"show"** (~2488 hits), **"get"** (~2184 hits), and **"give"** (~1171 hits).

However, looking only at the verbs starting with *A* that collocate with it (collocate search for `respect` and `a*_v`, group by lemmas), I see that **"accord"** is the most common (~165 hits), followed by **"afford"** (~61 hits). **"Award"** returns 4 hits.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody have an inside track on whether either or both (or all three, why not?) are correct?

It is a mistake to think that any are incorrect. All are correct and all have different nuances:

**to afford** = to provide (usually from one's resources);

**to accord** = to agree (upon);

**to award** = to give by way of judgement.

Which one you use will depend on the context.

The *frequency* of the use is no guide to which is correct or appropriate.

OED

> Afford II. **To provide, to yield.**
>
> **3. a. transitive. To give, provide, contribute; to grant, bestow, confer (a privilege, benefit, gift, etc.).Also with direct and indirect object.**
>
> 1957   Times 14 May 11/2   *The decision to afford British ships the facilities for using the Suez Canal again was announced.*
>
> 2000   A. Ghosh Glass Palace (2001) xxiii. 281   *Hardy..assumed that they would afford him the same indulgence and affection that he remembered from the past.*
>
> **Accord: 3. a. transitive. To give, bestow, award, esp. by deliberate decision or with full consent; to agree to, consent to, grant (a request or something requested). Also: to attribute. Frequently with to or indirect object. Also occasionally intransitive.**
>
> 1965   N.Y. Times Mag. Apr. 105/1   *A majority of mankind, both Afro-Asian and Western, do not accord each other a qualitatively equal humanity.*
>
> 2004   Q Sept. 138/3   *She ticks most of the boxes that should give her the maverick status accorded to Kate Bush or Joni Mitchell.*

MW:

> **Award**
>
> transitive verb
>
> **1 : to confer or bestow as being deserved or merited or needed**
>
> *award scholarships to disadvantaged students*

Comment: Thanks for an interesting perspective. While I agree that the frequency of them is now indication to which is correct, I think collocation plays an important role here, possibly more so than the shades of meaning that you've expalined so clearly.